# JXA (AppleScript) disabled other key on system.keystroke

Tags: keyboard, applescript, javascript-automation, mouse-keys

I trigger CMD+C to get the content highlighted to the clipboard.

My problem is that if the user does another key simultaneously, it breaks all the flow.

Do you know any solution (like blocking other keys or something)?

the code bellow

```
const system = Application('System Events');
     system.keystroke('c', {
        using: ['command down'],
     });
```